# linux boot splash plymouth logging

Tags: linux, boot

I'm want create my boot splash theme from plymouth-0.8.8 source code.
I built plymouth source flow these steps:

```
# ./configure --prefix=/usr --sysconfdir=/etc --localstatedir=/var --enable-tracing
# make && make install
```

After that, I create initrd with init file like that:

```
[
...
printf '\033[?25l' > /dev/tty7
/sbin/plymouthd --mode=boot --attach-to-session --pid-file=/run/initramfs/plymouth.pid --debug
/bin/plymouth show-splash
...
]
```

When boot completed, I want to see log file of plymouth, but I can't see that.

Please suggest me how to configure plymouth write log into a file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [Ubuntu Wiki](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Plymouth#Plymouth_Logs) says it's supposed to log in `/var/log/boot.log` by default, but you have to tell it the directory is writeable with `plymouth update-root-fs --read-write`.